# How to cross-compile a working Windows Tk dll?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I've found to my surprise that I can't cross-compile a working Windows Tk dll from the latest release source using the Linux mingw tools.  Compiling a working tclsh.exe was no problem.  The compiled tk86.dll complains that it can't find resource files compiled in and crashes.

According to the build commands echoed from the make process, the resources appear to have been built and included as expected.

On 64-bit Linux with mingw cross-compile tools installed, I cross-compile Tk 8.6.8:

In the win subdir:

```
$ ./configure --with-encoding=utf-8 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-threads --enable-64bit --with-tcl=/opt/tcl8.6.8/win
$ make tk86.dll
```

To test the result, on my Windows 10 computer I download the binary Tcl/Tk distribution from Thomas Perschak as recommended at https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/bindist.html

I put my new-compiled tk86.dll in place of the downloaded one.

```
> tclsh86.exe
% package require Tk
% button .b
FindResource() failed for buttons bitmap resource, resources in tk_base.rc must be linked into Tk dll or static executable
```

The interpreter then crashes.

I don't know if this is a bug in Tk or its build tools, or a configuration oversight on my part.  Work requirements disallow me from using precompiled binaries, so this is a showstopper for me.  Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Did it run the resource compiler?

Comment: tk.res.o was built, and according to commands echoed to console, it was one of the object files added to tk86.dll

Comment: I used a resource editor on Windows to verify that the dll contains all expected resource files.

Comment: Can you post the exact line calling the RC (windres)? Have you compared your procedure with documented ones (in kit builders, e.g.: https://kitcreator.rkeene.org/fossil/artifact/fa60b362d440121e)?

Comment: Line calling windres extracted from make output:  `x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres -o tk.res.o   --include "./../generic" --include "/opt/tcl8.6.8/generic" --include "./rc" "./rc/tk.rc"`

Comment: I tried using the kitcreator web interface to create a Windows tclkit including only Tcl and Tk, but it was non-functional for other reasons.

Comment: Strangely, I added "--enable-static --disable-shared" to the configure command above, in hopes of making extra sure that all necessary libs were compiled in, and in the build tk.res.o was not built and the resulting tk86.dll had no resources included at all.  A separate bug?

Comment: Here is the line from the kitcreator build log: `"x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres" -o tkbase.res.o  --define STATIC_BUILD --include "./../generic" --include "/tmp/kitcreator-web/builds/f3ab47d8d2060b9e4e29162f307df1d17529366f/build/kitcreator-0.11.0/tcl/build/tcl8.6.8/win/../generic" --include "/tmp/kitcreator-web/builds/f3ab47d8d2060b9e4e29162f307df1d17529366f/build/kitcreator-0.11.0/tcl/build/tcl8.6.8/win" --include "./rc" "./rc/tk_base.rc"
`

Comment: The problem does not exist in Tcl 8.6.4.

Comment: The problem does not exist in Tcl 8.6.7.

Comment: I can't work on this right now, but there seem to be other issues with x-compiled 8.6.8 also, e.g.: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/FrDqnT3y2qU